What do I tip, if anything, at Club Med Charlevoix (Québec)?
We'll be going at Club Med Charlevoix in Québec/Canada soon, and I'm wondering what should we tip.
Club Med Charlevoix is an all-inclusive, and some review sites boast that you can leave your wallet at your room, however

being used to travel in Québec (in non all-inclusive hotels)

we usually leave tip for the folks taking care of the room when we leave
we tip room service when we order


having been in all-inclusive resorts in the Caribbean (Dominican Republic, not Club Med)

we tip folks serving us when we leave our table
we tip folks serving us when we get a drink at the bar
we leave tip for folks doing the room every day
we tipped the luggage person who brought the luggage to our room
etc.



So, since it's our first time going to 1) a Club Med and 2) an all-inclusive in Québec/Canada, I'm not sure what's the un-written/ethical policy regarding tip there.

As far as I know, the only place where people would get offended by tiping is Japan. Even if tiping is not common people wouldn't mind being tipped, so when in doubt you can leave a tip.
